# Customer could not get order email when order is placed on magento store CE 1.9.2.1

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, order-email, smtp

I have used **SMTP Pro extension** for mails configuration. All emails works perfectly except email for order. Cron is setup correctly in server. Code to run on server is :

`php -f /home/magento/public_html/project/cron.php`

and **I have setup cron to run on every one minute**.
For quick fixes what i did is change in `order.php (public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php)`

**From**

```
$mailer->setQueue($emailQueue)->send();
```

**To**

```
$mailer->send();
```

And the emails are sent instatly whenever customer orders the product instead of queuing. But, what i need is the order need to be send through cron.
**Can you suggest me the best way to solve this problem**.?

Thanks.!

Answer (score 0):

After installing that extension if you want that your mail should sent from cron then change below setting ,

Login admin panel and

```
go to system->configuration->Aschroder Extensions->Smtp pro-> Queue Configuration->Queue Usage
```

And set for `cron` and your mail send from cron job your job is done